# Prolog, Returning list from 1 to N

Tags: prolog

Basically I'm working on a bigger problem, but how would I return a list from 1 to a number `n`? I'm new to this and a little confused. Also, would it be possible to pass this as a parameter in a function call?

like  `check(newlist(1, N), [L | Rl]);`

where `newlist` is a function call that returns the list between `1` and `N`?

Sorry if my terminology is off. It seems like a pretty basic problem but I'm still learning and getting down the concept of Prolog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Prolog, you don't really have functions that return values. You have predicates that unify variables. With that in mind, you'd write something like this:

```
range(1, N, ResultOfRange),
check(ResultOfRange, [L, Rl]).
```

With that said, think about the base condition of `range` and then figure out how you'd build on that to make a predicate yielding a whole range of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Prolog' library. For instance, in SWI-Prolog there is [numlist](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=numlist/3)/3. You can pass a predicate 'by name', assuming the callee will invoke it by means of [call](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=call/2)/N.

```
check(ListBuilder, N) :-
  call(ListBuilder, 1, N, L),
  ...

main :-
  check(numlist, 10),
  ...
```